# Observable.throw replacement in rxjs 5.5.2

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm migrating to `rxjs@5.5.2` and using lettable operators... I also update `Observable` static methods. I wonder what is the counterpart of `Observable.throw` and `import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';`.

Should I import ugly `_throw`?

`import { _throw } from 'rxjs/observable/throw';`

Or there's a better way. Honestly I liked static methods on `Observable`, and now it seems that all static creating methods like `of`, `from` should be imported from `rxjs/observable/<methodName>` ?

Comment: Had the same question. Unfortunately, the 5.5 docs mention only the (now "lettable") operators, but not the static methods.

The disadvantage of importing the static methods is that they have very short names lacking the observable context and looking more like syntax elements ("from" and "of"), or even coinciding with keywords ("throw" and "if"). Therefore I tend to import them with alias names ("_throw" as "ObservableThrow", "of" as "ObservableOf", or "empty" as "EmptyObservable").

Comment: Of course we could still use the old method of importing 'rxjs/add/...', but that has the same disadvantages as for the operators.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'm still getting my head round 5.5 but it looks like now instead of importing throw use **ErrorObservable**.

```
// import { _throw } from 'rxjs/observable/throw';
import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';

ErrorObservable.create('error');
```

From this [guide](https://youtu.be/s7gK__dC-_g?t=12m49s) it looks like it has to be **_throw** to avoid a keyword clash (the rest of the video is good for getting started with 5.5)

Comment: You can do this more easy by use of _throw('error') which does exactly what you do but its less code to write

Answer (score 40):

In continuation to Mick's answer, in the rxjs version 6 `_throw` is replaced by `throwError`

```
 import {Observable, throwError} from 'rxjs';
```

[RxJS Migration Guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md)

Comment: This question is specific to 5.5.2, isn't it?

Comment: yes but google give it as an answer for 6.x.x  i skipped the latest 5.x.x to go right to 6. Many people (like me) will not even know about the _throw function.

Answer (score 13):

Yes `_throw` is correct(this will do exactly what JayChase wrote but is less code). You do the same with `of`:

```
import {of} from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import {_throw} from 'rxjs/observable/throw';

// ...
   // ...
   if (result) {
       return of(result as T);
   } else {
       return _throw('error');
   }
}
```

Comment: in version 6, _throw is now exported as throwError : import {Observable, throwError} from 'rxjs';

Comment: @bleuscyther - You should put this as an answer for the benefit of searchers. I've just waded though pages of SO answers, but your comment is now the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ok It would be better if @Mick appended the to his answer but just in case i will and the anwer

Comment: This question is specific to 5.5.2, so i guess i leave it like this?

Answer (score 7):

For Angular 5 and above:

```
import{Http} from '@angular/http';
import {HttpClient,HttpResponse,HttpErrorResponse  } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import {Employee} from './employee';

import { Observable,throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map,catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';  


@Injectable() 
export class employeeService{
constructor(private _http:Http){  }
 getEmployees():Observable<Employee[]>{
    return this._http.get('YOUR URL')
                     .pipe(
                         map((res: Response) => res.json()),
                         catchError(this.handleError)
                        );
                     //.pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
 }
 handleError(error:HttpErrorResponse){
    console.log(error);
    return throwError(error.message);
 }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wonder which one to use - ErrorObservable vs _throw, here's something from the 5.5.2 source core

```
RxJs library 5.5.2 - throw.ts file

import {  ErrorObservable  } from './ErrorObservable';

export const _throw = ErrorObservable.create;
```

So, it doesn't matter.