# TypeError: rxjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Observable.throw is not a function

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6

Here is my file userdata.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Data } from './userdata';

@Injectable()
export class UserDataService {

  url : "http://localhost:4200/assets/data/userdata.json";
  constructor(private http:Http) { }  

  getDataWithObservable() : Observable<any>{
      return this.http.get(this.url)
            .pipe(
              map(this.extractData),
              catchError(this.handleErrorObservable)
            );
  }

    private extractData(res: Response) 
    {
        let body = res.json();      
        return body;
    }

    private handleErrorObservable (error: Response | any) 
    {   
        return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

I m getting the following Error :

> TypeError: rxjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Observable.throw is not a
>   function

Comment: which version of angular are you using? rxjs 6?

Comment: Can you share `your package.json`

Comment: "rxjs": "^6.0.0" : this is what is in my package.json so yes its 6 only

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mysql": "^2.15.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  }

Comment: You are using angular 6 mate not Angular 2

Comment: see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47097606/observable-throw-replacement-in-rxjs-5-5-2/47106240)

Comment: Mate you are using `HttpModule` which is deprecated you should use `HttpClientModule` Instead

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: ya thats version 6 !!! @Vikas

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Import:

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
```

Usage:

```
return throwError(err);
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Observable.throw()` has been deleted.](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3733)

Try using `Observable.throwError()`. Apparently the definitions aren't up to date just yet.

You can import it using `import { throwError } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: No It haven't worked ! I added import { throwError } from 'rxjs/observable'; and changed my function to Observable.throwError() but nothing happened

Comment: @JitendraAhuja are you using angular 6?

Comment: No angular 2 @MetaPyroxia

Comment: Also tried adding import { throwError } from 'rxjs/create'; but didnot work

Comment: Wait , this is my package.json file's dependencies : "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mysql": "^2.15.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  }

Comment: @JitendraAhuja your import statement is not correct then for angular 2 `import {Observable} from 'rxjs';` it should be 
`import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`

Comment: @JitendraAhuja from your package it seems you are using angular 6

Comment: Try `import { throwError } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: `import { _throw } from 'rxjs/observable/throw';  ` and `return _throw('error');`

Comment: @Vikas While that looks like it'd work, I wouldn't recommend using an internal function that might go away without warning.

Comment: Ok import { throwError } from 'rxjs'; worked for me. Thx @MetaPyroxia

Comment: use it without `Observable.`, just `throwError(...`

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 8 use

```
throwError(new NotFoundError("Resource Not Found."))
```

Don't use

```
Observable.throw(new NotFoundError("Resource Not Found."))
```

Complete example

```
catchError((error:Response) => {
    if(error.status === 404) {
      return throwError(new NotFoundError("Resource Not Found."));
    }
    return throwError(new AppError(error));
});
```